# Can't toggle the button in Microsoft list

Tags: sharepoint

https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/yesno-toggle-format

I follow the instruction on this page and received this error [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr6n9.png)
and I can't toggle the button after that. Can everyone have the ways to fix this

Comment: Is it happening for this column only? Can you try creating a new list and column and try using the JSON there to see if you can reproduce the issue in another list as well?

Answer (score 0):

This issue cannot be reproduced from my end.
[image]

Please check as following to narrow down the issue:

1.Have you used the Yes/No column to a toggle?

2.Please check the format.
[image]
Compare the examples given in your links:

[image]

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: copied the JSON, but toggle was not possible. The problem was in **row 26**:

```
"YesNoColumnInternalName": "=if(@currentField , '0' , '1' )"
```

Although my column title is called "Published", intuitively changing the code to

```
"Published": "=if(@currentField , '0' , '1' )"
```

did **not** do the trick.

**Solution:** I checked for the column name using Chrome's *right-click* "Inspect" tool. The HTML is:

```
<div role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" class="ms-DetailsHeader-cell is-actionable root-185" data-is-draggable="true" draggable="true" data-automationid="ColumnsHeaderColumn" data-item-key="YesNo0" style="width: 150px;">
```

The important part here is:

```
data-item-key="YesNo0"
```

Once I changed the initial JSON in row 26 accordingly, it worked like a charm:

```
"YesNo0": "=if(@currentField , '0' , '1' )"
```